# Interchanging Limit and Integral sign

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, contour-integration, uniform-convergence, hardy-spaces

I'm reading a book on composition operators, and the author makes the following claim:

Given a self-map of the unit disc, and a $H^2$ function $f$, where $H^2$ is the Hardy space, if we fix a radius $r<1$ and define $f_m$ to be the $m$th partial sums in the power series expansion of $f$, then 
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(\phi(re^{i\theta}))|^2d\theta = \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f_m(\phi(re^{i\theta}))|^2d\theta, 
$$
which follows from the fact that $f_m \circ \phi$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of the unit disc to $f \circ \phi$.  And this is all well and good, but when the function becomes revalued by using the continuity of the modulus, that is, when we write
$$
|f(\phi(re^{i\theta}))|^2 = \lim_{m \to \infty}|f_m(\phi(re^{i\theta}))|^2,
$$
how are we guaranteed that the convergence is still uniform?

Any help is appreciated.